# webservlet 3.0 - utf8 url pattern

Tags: servlets, tomcat7

How can i use utf8 url for webservlets?

```
@WebServlet("/nonlatinchars")
```

for example:

```
@WebServlet("/руский")
```

PS. I don't have problem for utf8 parameter value.

webservlet 3.0, tomcat7

Answer (score 0):

```
URIEncoding="UTF-8"
```

in server.xml of tomcat added, restart tomcat, Problem solved

Before

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443"/>
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443"/>
```

After

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
<Connector port="8081" protocol="HTTP/1.1" connectionTimeout="20000" redirectPort="8443" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```